# Using SqlAlchemy .filter() and .contains()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using the of `request.data` to make a sqlalchemy query but running into an issue:

```
@app.route('/update', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def update_gh():
    y = request.data
    print(y)
    # "7090364643"
    x = db_session.query(Candidate).filter(Candidate.url.contains("7090364643")).first()
    print(x)
    # Prints the record as expected
```

This works. I am copying and pasting in the printed value of `y` into `.contains()`.

However, this isn't working:

```
@app.route('/update', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def update_gh():
    y = request.data
    print(type(y))
    # <type 'str'>
    x = db_session.query(Candidate).filter(Candidate.url.contains(y)).first()
    print(x)
    # None
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does it work when I manually input the value of `y` but not when I put in the variable `y`?

Update:

The request originates from a button click:

```
function searchDB(profile_url) {
        console.log(profile_url);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/update_greenhouse',
            data: JSON.stringify(profile_url),
            contentType: "application/json"
        })
    }
```

Comment: How are you passing `y` to the view?

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not passing it to the view, I'm just trying to query a DB

Comment: I test on database, the `.contains` works as expected. You could print the actual value (may be use `r` flag)  to see what happens.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Python2

Comment: @MorganAllen: you are passing in data into the view, with `request.data`. How are you passing that in? How is the request made? What does `print(repr(y))` produce in that case?

Comment: Ahh ok. The request is coming from a Ajax Call. Updating the question to reflect it.

Comment: You are posting JSON but not decoding the data.

Comment: When I try `y = json.loads(request.data)` I get an error: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: `JSON.stringify(url)` produces the JSON string `"http://127.0.0.1:5000/update"`, so in Python `y` will be set to `'"http://127.0.0.1:5000/update"'` (note the double quotes are *part of the value*).

Comment: Ahhh! completely missed that. Thank you

Comment: hmm still getting the error, updating question